# getting data and append it by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have my data returning in by ajax but it doesn't show in proper way.

[image: one]

as you see in my screenshot i can get the id correctly in `data-id""` but in my form action it doesn't return correclty.

## Code

```
var html = '<tr>';
html += '<td>'+data.data.id+'</td>';
html += '<td>'+data.data.code+'</td>';
html += '<td>'+data.data.name+'</td>';
// this part
html += '<td><Form method="DELETE" action="{{route("customers.destroy", '+data.data.id+')}}"> @csrf @method("DELETE")<button type="submit" data-id="'+data.data.id+'" class="btn btn-block btn-sm delete btn-danger">Delete</button></form></td></tr>';

$('#table_data').prepend(html);
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: Did you write the js in a blade file?

Comment: how to you get data-id in javascript code? send your javascript code

Comment: @jagad89 yes i have scripts yield in my layout i can add scripts from my views

Comment: `action="{{route('customers.destroy')}} +data.data.id"` try this

Comment: @BInjalPatel my script sends data to controller and store it in database and return the data in success method i get my data, as my data are completly showing there is no issue with data only the part that i should get the id in my form action. even i can get my id 1 line below my form action as you see in my screenshot.

Comment: @jagad89 that would return error as my route is resource it requires to id be included `Missing required parameters for [Route: customers.destroy] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't write js in php. `{{route("customers.destroy", '+data.data.id+')}}` this won't work as you are using a js variable inside a php echo. a solution would be make a js variable with url. something like

```
var url = '{{ route("customers.destroy", ":id") }}';
url = url.replace(':id', data.data.id);
```

and use it now like

```
 html += '<td><form method="POST" action="+url+">
 @csrf @method("DELETE")
 <button type="submit" data-id="'+data.data.id+'" class="btn btn-block btn-sm delete btn-danger">Delete</button>
 </form></td></tr>';
```

> i have changed form method from `delete` to `post` as you can't submit a form with `delete` method.